# Pythonic way to build a Combination String

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have one list, like so,

```
a = ['dog','cat','mouse']
```

I want to build a list that is a combination of the all the list elements and  looks like,

```
ans = ['cat-dog', 'cat-mouse','dog-mouse']
```

This is what I came up with,

```
a = ['dog','cat','mouse']
ans = []
for l in (a):
    t= [sorted([l,x]) for x in a if x != l]
    ans.extend([x[0]+'-'+x[1] for x in t])
print list(set(sorted(ans)))
```

Is there a simpler and a more pythonic way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How important is the ordering?

```
>>> a = ['dog','cat','mouse']
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> ['-'.join(el) for el in combinations(a, 2)]
['dog-cat', 'dog-mouse', 'cat-mouse']
```

Or, to match your example:

```
>>> ['-'.join(el) for el in combinations(sorted(a), 2)]
['cat-dog', 'cat-mouse', 'dog-mouse']
```

Comment: A `sorted` will take care of it if it is important: `['-'.join(c) for c in combinations(sorted(a),2)]` yields the answer given in the question text.

Comment: @MarkReed I must have imagined the "couple of sorted" then :P

Comment: You were just too fast, @JonClements.  Thanks, though. :)

Answer (score 4):

The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> map('-'.join, itertools.combinations(a, 2))
['dog-cat', 'dog-mouse', 'cat-mouse']
```

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` is surely the way to go here. If you want to do it only with build-ins, use:

```
a = ['dog','cat','mouse']
ans = [x + '-' + y for x in a for y in a if x < y]
```